# Script to copy data but skip errors, blanks and loading

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have a spreadsheet for checking instagram followers of multiple accounts (using formulas) and I would like a script that just copies the cell that contains the number of followers to another cell and overwrites only if new information is available (skip errors and blanks). As it is very common for this formula to give an error or take a long time to load, I think it would be interesting to use a script to always keep the latest information visible. Would that be possible? I found the formula below and it works but doesn't skip errors, blanks or loading... and overwrites anyway.

```
function copyValuesOnly() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var source = ss.getRange('ALL!K8:K')
source.copyTo(ss.getRange('ALL!L8'), {contentsOnly: true});
};
```

I've tried to change the script but I don't understand it very well. If someone can help me with a script (which I imagine to be simple) I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

**Using setValues() method in sections between cells that should be left alone**

This function copies only values that are numbers greater than zero it skips the rest but uses setValues() in sections to store the data as quickly as possible and can greatly speed up the write process.

```
function copyValuesOnly() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");//update sheet name
  const sr = 2;//update data start row
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr, 11, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1).getValues().flat();
  const obj = vs.reduce((acc,e,i) => {
    if(!isNaN(e) && e > 0) {//this determines what it good data that should be copied the other values will be skipp
      if(acc.buffer.length == 0) {
        acc.pA.push(acc.pA.length);
        acc[`${acc.pA[acc.pA.length - 1]}`] = {sr: i + sr, elems:[[e]]};
        acc.buffer.push(e)
      } else {
        acc[`${acc.pA[acc.pA.length - 1]}`].elems.push([e]);
        acc.buffer.push(e);
      }
    } else {
      if(acc.buffer.length > 0) {
        acc.buffer = [];
      }
    }
    return acc;
  },{pA:[],buffer:[]});
  obj.pA.forEach(p => {
    let v = obj[p].elems;
    sh.getRange(obj[p].sr,12,v.length,v[0].length).setValues(v)
  });
  const end = "is near";
}
```

This is a somewhat simpler version but it does the same thing without using a buffer.

```
function copyValuesOnly() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");//update sheet name
  const sr = 2;//update data start row
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr, 11, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1).getValues().flat();
  const obj = vs.reduce((acc, e, i) => {
    if (!isNaN(e) && e > 0) {
      if (acc.counter == 0) {
        acc.pA.push(acc.pA.length);
        acc[`${acc.pA[acc.pA.length - 1]}`] = { r: i + sr, c: 12, elems: [[e]] };
        acc.counter++;
      } else {
        acc[`${acc.pA[acc.pA.length - 1]}`].elems.push([e]);
      }
    } else {
      acc.counter = 0;
    }
    return acc;
  }, { pA: [], counter: 0 });
  obj.pA.forEach(p => {
    let v = obj[p].elems;
    sh.getRange(obj[p].r, obj[p].c, v.length, v[0].length).setValues(v)
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi! This script doesn't seen to do anything to the sheet. Nothing happened.

Comment: Perrhaps you should have supplied some of your data for testing